# Calculating Multi-phase Buck Output Capacitance with WS2812b LED Strips as Load

Tags: buck, led-strip

EDIT: New info at the end based on more information I've found.

I'm currently designing a fan/RGB controller for use in a pc that uses 12V from an 8pin PCIE connector as the input.

The most complicated stage of this is a fairly high power supply (75W) for 5V digitally addressable RGB strips. These strips seem to all be based on WS2812b LED chips which can use up to 60mA at full white brightness and wanting to drive quite a lot of these I subsequently chose a 4 phase buck design to try and minimise thermal constraints.

I've been working through this [TI design note](https://www.ti.com/lit/slva882) and have managed pretty well so far but have run into some issues when it comes to calculating the output capacitance. The load in the document (a CPU) seems to be very different from my intended load and my assumption is that the formulas for output capacitance aren't really applicable because of this.

Based on my assumption that a WS2812b strip creates a step load of a maximum of 60mA every 30us the capacitance suggested by the formulas for transient response is negligible (below 1uF). The output capacitance according to the design note is then instead the amount needed to minimise vout ripple and comes out at around 4uF with the chosen 500kHz switching frequency and single phase ripple current of 1.35A. This seems very low to me and suggests I'm missing or don't understand something.

The main thing I don't know how to account for is that the LED strip is dimmed via a 400Hz PWM signal internally.
Is this what I actually need to design the output capacitance for, rather than the step load of turning individual LEDs on and off?

There is also the inductance from the fairly long wires between this buck converter and the actual LED strips which then have more wire between them due to the daisy chaining used. Do I need to account for this with additional output capacitance or something else?

Searching around I've found suggestions that buck converters can drive LED's with effectively no output capacitance because they can operate as constant current sources due to the inductor smoothing and in other cases that I would need something on the order of 60mF per phase to smooth the ripple so I am quite confused and would appreciate any help with this.

**Buck Specifications (Per Phase)**

- Vin = 12V
- Vout = 5V
- Switching Frequency = 500kHz
- I out = 4.5A
- Initial target I ripple = 1.35A (30%)
- Actual I ripple = 940.9mA
- L = 6.2uH
- Vin ripple = 100mV (Hard maximum. Really don't want to pollute the 12V rail)
- Vout ripple = 100mV (This is fairly flexible, more an issue of voltage drop over the strip length meaning less is better)

**Parts**

- Controller: [TPS40090-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS40090-Q1)
- Gate Driver: [MIC4605](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MIC4605)
- HS & LS FETs: [TPH8R903NL](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=14068&prodName=TPH8R903NL)
- Inductor: [7447706062](https://www.we-online.com/catalog/datasheet/7447706062.pdf)

**Update**

Managed to find more info on the internal PWM of the WS2812b [here](https://circuitcellar.com/research-design-hub/design-solutions/the-analog-side-of-pwm-leds/). They seem to use a clock that drifts quite a lot so with many all in parallel like in an LED strip it's possible for all of them to turn on/off at once if the PWM edges all end up synchronised.

With this being the case, I've altered the step current to the full rating of each phase (4.5A) and settled on around 31.4uF of MLCC per phase for now.
I'm also going to leave room for several bulk electrolytics since the load is pretty far from the actual buck output.
I've swapped the inductor as well but this is because the new one has data for AC and core losses so I can properly predict the power dissipation.

Comment: 4-phase buck for 15 A seems excessive but if it’s cheap and available, why not. Please check/explain _”ripple current which is still only <4uF”_.

Comment: Multi-phase converters are typically used for much higher currents, or where the ripple voltage specification is much stricter, such as low-voltage CPU supplies, or where your buck converter is doing a higher-ratio conversion, or where you're space constrained with the amount of capacitors you can fit... This is why the most common place to see multi-phase buck converters is on computer motherboards... >100A, 0.9V, 30mV ripple, and it has to be "as small as possible".

Comment: @winny I've attempted to clarify that statement in the question. The design note says the output capacitance is the higher of either the amount needed for the transient response needed or the amount needed for a given vout ripple (the latter is the 4uF).

Comment: I realise 4 phase is a lot in this case but its quite a bit of current for only a single phase and I was hoping to avoid needing a lot of cooling. The controller I've selected is 2-4 phase anyway so I may as well do the 4. This is a one off and is fairly expensive so the extra 2 phases don't add that much to the total BOM.

Comment: Depends on the frequency, inductance and ESR of the capacitor, but yes, 4 uF sounds low. In general for TI switchers, they have some proprietary feedback mechanism with super fast response for load steps. What's your inductance.

Comment: 10uH is what I selected. The specific controller is a [TPS40090-Q1](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS40090-Q1) in case that helps.

Comment: What current ripple do you get with 500 kHz, 5/12 duty cycle, 1 phase for ease of calculation and 10 uH? U=L x dI/dt => Ut = L x ΔI => (12-5)*5/(12x500k) = L x ΔI. Solve for ΔI.

Comment: My bad, I used 30% ripple as the initial target and forgot that as I've picked the inductor size and changed the switching frequency for other reasons the actual ripple is only 583mA. That lowers the output capacitance result to only 1.5uF.

Having thought about it more I'm thinking I really need to know more about the behaviour of the load. I don't actually know if the individual LED packages switch their duty cycles as soon as they get their 24 bits and swap to passing through and if the PWM is synchronised between the packages.

Comment: Why not use the 12V version of WS2812?

Comment: I don't have control over the actual LEDs used. The PC market decided that for addressable LEDs everything is 5V. If it was just LED strips then I could use whatever but a lot of them are directly integrated into products such as GPU/CPU waterblocks and reservoirs.
The current standard definitely has its issues between the 5V, two different connectors (one being too small and 4 pins with one missing) and generally small wiring meaning it really isn't suited to many LEDs.